# I am trying to programatically add a webbrowser to a tab but the bit of code ("WebBrowser") i need is a namespace even though it is never mentioned

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a Web browser that has tabs and because of this I need to add controls to the new tabs programatically and then it spits out an error('WebBrowser' is a namespace but is used like a 'type')

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WebBrowser;

namespace myWebBrowser
{
    public partial class EzWeb : Form
    {
        public EzWeb()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This app was made by Eoin", "About");
        }

        private void ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            this.Close();
        }

        private void TabControl1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("If you wish to create a new tab or remove this tab please go to Tab Control in the top left of the screen.");
        }

        private void NewTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabPage tab = new TabPage();
            tab.Text = "New tab";
            tabControl1.Controls.Add(tab);
            WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser(); 

        }

        private void DeleteSelectedTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(tabControl1.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to c#.  Please bear that in mind when answering.

Comment: Remove the line "using WebBrowser;"

Comment: WebBrowser is a class, not a namespace.  `using _______` at the top of the file is for importing namespaces.

Comment: i have removed that line and nothing has changed

Comment: That error should go away when you re-compile.  Have you created your own WebBrowser class or namespace in your project?  I've copied your code into a new project and it works.

Comment: I did change the namespace from WebBrowser to myWebBrowser before asking because I was having this problem since I thought it would fix it

Comment: You still have a `WebBrowser` namespace in your project.  Hit CTRL+SHIFT+F, search the entire project for "namespace WebBrowser" and update every instance you find.  The code in the question sees "WebBrowser" and think you're referring to your own namespace, because its still around someplace.

Comment: @Amy thank you very much for helping. I was so close to just deleting my project and giving up.

Comment: In the future, when you want to rename something, click on the thing you want to rename and press F2 (this is the default key, yours might be different).  This will prompt you to enter a new name and will automatically replace that symbol with the new name throughout the project.  It's convenient.

Comment: @Eoin Don't give up.  Stick with it, ask for help, and walk away for a while before coming back.  You can get it.